# Reference request for worked-out examples (solutions) on multivariable calculus (in particular inverse and implicit function theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

**Reference Request :** Is there any book or notes available where I can find a lot of examples / worked-out solutions of problems on multivariable calculus (the topics must include Inverse and Implicit function theorem)? Thank you.

Comment: Shaum's outline.  If you can understand French, you may consult math books for Agrégation.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Do you mean Schaum's Advanced calculus? Or Vector analysis? Can you specify the book?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I see this book recommended at many places but unfortunately the Inverse and Implicit function theorems are not even mentioned in this book.

Comment: I'm sorry about that.  Unluckily, expect Fitzpatrick's Advanced Calculus and Rudin's PMA, I haven't read other great classics, so I can't give you an English one.  If you know French, you may take, for example, *Analyse en L3* for a general proof as well as example of these two IFTs in Banach space.